# Casecomment public and published

Tags: case-comment

What is the difference between public and published? There is a checkbox for public but according to the docoumentation

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_casecomment.htm

there is no public field on casecomment.

What does checking the public checkbox actually do?

Comment: They're the same field. The documentation says what the field does. It controls if users can see the comment in the self-service portal.

Comment: I could not find documentation stating that they were the same field, do you have any official documentation? @AdrianLarson

Comment: I have experience. Also, you can just go in and edit a specific record using the API Name and see for yourself that the value gets changed.